# Can't scrape <ui-tags> in python. Unsure why?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape AFL odds from betfair (https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/australian-rules).
I am fairly new to webscraping however have managed to scrape odds from other bookies but i am having trouble with Betfair. The data I need is within a "ui-view" tag which doesn't seem to open when I use Beautiful soup to get the HTML.

I've tried unsuccessfully to use selenium when loading the page to get the odds.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint as pp

BETFAIR_URL = "https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/australian-rules"

#functions
def parse(url):
    # open url

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        'C:/Users/Maroz/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')
    # opens page
    driver.get(url)

    # parses as html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    # closes same
    driver.quit()


    return soup

betfair_soup = parse(BETFAIR_URL)

pp.pprint(betfair_soup)

#edit to show that it finds nothing in the span i need which is within the ui-#tags
price = betfair_soup.find_all("span", {"class": "bet-button-price"})
pp.pprint(price)
#output is []
```

I expected the betfair_soup to contain the infomation within this tag ui-view
however it remains closed when printed to the terminal.
Won't let me post an image because this is my first post but you might be able to see a screenshot of the tags I am trying to access here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWipi.jpg

As requested here is the html I get in terminal:

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">window['isIE'] = true;</script>
        <![endif]-->
<!-- Set ie10 class: http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/ -->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script>
        (function () {
            var isIE10 = Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')();

            if (isIE10) {
                document.documentElement.className += ' ie10';
            }
        })();

    </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<bf-meta-tags></bf-meta-tags>
<bf-tooltip-guide><div class="tooltip-guide-container" ng-controller="TooltipGuideController as controller"><!-- --></div></bf-tooltip-guide>
<!-- --><ui-view></ui-view> #INFO IS IN HERE
<script src="//ie2eds.cdnppb.net/resources/eds/bundle/vendor-assets-min_4146.js"></script>
<script src="//ie2eds.cdnppb.net/resources/eds/bundle/bf-eds-static-client.min_4146_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I put a comment where the odds are located, when i view the page source the tags are also closed, so there isn't any way of me showing you what i see when i inspect element on the odds box other than the photo link i posted above^

edit: After trying suggestion to wait for ui-view to load this is the entire response, I still couldn't access the information in the span tags though.
https://pastebin.com/v6JzYa6V

**FINAL EDIT**: Problem solved! Thank you to everyone for your suggestions and special thanks to S Ahmed for his persistence in solving this for me!

Comment: when I open page then I see `"Our Software detects that you may be accessing the Betfair website from a country that Betfair does not accept bets from."` it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Could you post part of the html you are getting from the chromedriver/beautifulsoup and from the browser for pointing out the differences?

Comment: I don't see `find()` or `find_all()` in your code so soup can have full HTML not only `"ui-view"`. Selenium has own methods (`find_element(s)_by_XXX`) to find something on page. I can't see HTML but If `"ui-view"` is in `<iframe>` then you have to use `switch_to.frame(...)` in Selenium to get HTML form `<iframe>`

Comment: do you see this data in browser/Selenium when you run script with Selenium ? Maybe browser/Selenium needs time to fill `<ui-view>` with data. Maybe you have to use `time.sleep(..)` before you get `page_source`. Or maybe you have to click something to see this data - and then javascript load this data - then your script has to also click the same element.

Comment: you could try pastebin.com the response.text so we can test. (Is that really the entire response as I don't see the open and close html tags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it takes time to load the content of the `<ui-view>` tag and it is loaded by javascript. Try to wait for an internal element to be present before getting the source of the page.

**Try this:**

```
def parse(url):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"main-wrapper")))

    except:
        pp.pprint("Exception")

    finally:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        return soup
        driver.quit()
```

You have to import the following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Edit:**
Try waiting for the `span.bet-button-price` to be present instead of the `#main-wrap`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.bet-button-price")))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. This worked partially for me (Yay!, progress) it loaded the ui-view tag, however i still can't seem to access the span tag... I am trying to look through the html now to see why...

Comment: Instead of waiting for the `main wrap`, try waiting for the span you need to work on.

Replace the waiting code with this:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR ,"span.bet-button-price")))
`

Comment: I tried but it doesn’t let me due to lack of reputation :/ sorry. It says recorded but not publically displayed.